# How to draw a Wire Connecting two points using andengine

Tags: path, sprite, andengine

I am New to AndEngine programming . i am developing a small game where user can touch two points and then i have to draw a physical wire between those two points.
i dont want to draw a plane line between the points.i want it to look like a physical wire or rope . how to do it  .or what should i use.

i have few idea of path modifier in andengine which can be used to create path between two points.

Want to know if thats the way to go aboout it and if yes then how to bring real wire or rope effect(will i need some kind of sprite sheet animation)
Or any other method .

If anyone can provide code segments it will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to tackle this is by linking a certain amount of bodies together. Of course, the more bodies you link together, the better simulation of a "rope" you'll get, but also, you'll get worse performance. In order to find your "sweet spot" between performance and smoothness, you'll need to try different numbers of body links until you're happy with the results.

For some code, and short tutorial take a look [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/10/05/basic-box2d-rope/). Please not this is a Box2d tutorial and not an AndEngine one so the code is in [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript). However it should be pretty much analogous to the AndEngine Box2d extension, which I assume you are using. Anyway, that should give you a good place to start.